# Using an event only in Designer View before run time in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, events, user-controls

I guess this is a really odd and rare question!!

I've made a certain Label control that inherits the `System.Windows.Forms.Label` object and thus becomes visible and usable in the designer view. When I drag the label to a form and Visual Studio creates an instance of it, I want it to open an input box and ask me what it's text should be. I overrided the `OnCreateControl` event and it's working but the problem is that the same thing happens when I run the program, but I just want it to work in the designer view **before run time**. How should I check/avoid the situation?

Here is the code:

```
protected override void OnCreateControl()
{
        base.OnCreateControl();
        this.Text = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter text: ");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the property `DesignMode` to find out, whether the Component is designed at the moment or not:

```
protected override void OnCreateControl()
{
   base.OnCreateControl();
   if (DesignMode)
        this.Text = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter text: ");
}
```